# Angular-bootstrap 3-column layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Hi i am trying to write the following layout in angular-bootstrap.But i am new to angular-bootstrap.

```
                 checkbox label1        checkbox label2             checkbox label3

                  label4                 label5                       label6
                  textbox                textbox                      textbox

                  label7                 label8                       label9
                  textbox                textbox                      textbox

                  radio label10          label11                      label12   label13
                  radio label14          textbox                      textbox   textbox

                                         label14   label15
                                         textbox   textbox
```

Please help me with the code for the above layout.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score -1):

You should check out:

http://www.layoutit.com/

It helps with designing the layout with bootstrap

below is a template I created that may help with your layout

http://bit.ly/1GjZ6XQ

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using CSS columns?

W3c has an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename) and [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

It's surprisingly well supported now too.